# PHP5-CGI doen'st terminate

Tags: apache-2.2, php5

I've a Plesk 9.5.4 server on Debian with PHP 5.2.6-1+lenny13, which keeps its `php5-cgi` process continuously active. I edited the `/etc/apache2/conf.d/fcgid.conf` and changed the values (and checked if the config was loaded anyway, which was true).

```
IdleTimeout 500
ProcessLifeTime 360
```

But still the process keeps alive for over an hour, and there is no activity for longer than half a hour.

Anyone knows what the problem can be?

Answer (score 0):

CGI process are kept "alive" so they can handle requests immediately. They do not terminate after a single request, but are often configured to handle 500-5000 requests until they get replaced with a new one.

The relevant config options are

```
PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=60
PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=5000
```

---

## CGI process management

The web server does not care care itself about handling 50+ PHP-CGI instances that may handle requests, but leaves this job to the CGI server. The CGI server itself keeps a pool of PHP-CGI instances running. It also kills them when they are not needed anymore and starts them when required.

## CGI server configuration

### `IdleTimeout`

tells the CGI process manager how long to wait for the CGI process to return a response.

#### Example:

The web server gets a HTTP request, sends that to the CGI server, CGI server relays that to the PHP-CGI process. Now the PHP-CGI process computes and computes and takes 1 minute to finish. Since the timeout is 120, everything is fine.

Now another request comes in, and the computation is harder, and the PHP-CGI process takes 10 minutes to finish. After 2 minutes, the CGI server reaches the CGI process' idle timeout and decides not to wait any longer.
It returns an error to the HTTP server: "no data retrieved, idle timeout".

### `ProcessLifetime`

is the number of seconds that a CGI process may be kept running. After that it's replaced with a new one.

Comment: Used this in the config : IdleTimeout 500
  ProcessLifeTime 360, so normaly they would be killed after 360 seconds

Comment: Yes, this is clear, but the process isn't be replaced, but the process remains for days and longer.

Comment: @Martijn it's probably because of the other settings I mentioned which keep a minimum number of processes around regardless of timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

**mod_fastcgi**

Check your setting for

> -**minProcesses** n (5)
>       The minimum total number of dynamic FastCGI application instances
>   allowed to run at any one time without being killed off by the process
>   manager (due to lack of demand).

It defaults to 5.

**mod_fcgid**

Check your setting for

> **FcgidMinProcessesPerClass**
>
> This directive sets the minimum number of
>   processes that will be retained in a process class after finishing
>   requests.
>
> This setting will apply to all applications spawned for this server or
>   virtual host. Use FcgidCmdOptions to apply this setting to a single
>   application.